# Postgres, query on current day takes 5X of runtime

Tags: postgresql, runtime

I'm working on a heroku project of a food delivery company.
I'm analyzing the queries of each endpoint in order to get a faster response from API.

Working on it, I've notice a strange behaviour of postgres query runtime.

This is the query:

```
SELECT orders.id, orders.user_id, orders.address_id, orders.content, orders.recorder, orders.payment_type, orders.delivery_id, orders.delivery_price, orders.price, orders.subtotal, orders.delivery_time, orders.calculated_pickup_time, orders.status, users.name, users.surname, users.mobile, addresses.name as addresses_name, addresses.surname as addresses_surname, addresses.mobile as addresses_mobile, addresses.street, addresses.city, restaurants.city_id, cities.name as cities_name, provinces.name as provincies_name FROM orders
   LEFT JOIN users on orders.user_id = users.id
   LEFT JOIN addresses on orders.address_id = addresses.id
   left join restaurants on ((jsonb(orders.content -> 0) -> 'restaurant_id')::text = restaurants.id::text)
   left join cities on (restaurants.city_id = cities.id)
   left join provinces on (cities.province_id = provinces.id) where orders.delivery_time > '2021-04-24 00:00:00' AND orders.delivery_time < '2021-04-25 02:00:00' ORDER BY orders.calculated_pickup_time DESC limit 1000
```

It takes <1s of runtime to give a response from db.
Now, the strange behaviour is that, if I change the delivery_time conditions, putting the current date I get a 5s of runtime.
In this query for example I just change the start date reducing it by 24h, what I expected by this query is that the runtime was faster than first query, but It takes 5X more.

```
orders.delivery_time > '2021-04-25 00:00:00' AND orders.delivery_time < '2021-04-25 02:00:00'
```

What's your opinion about?

Comment: Could you show us the DDL from the tables involved? And also the result from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) from this query?

Comment: In `psql` what does `show timezone;` return?

Comment: did the stat of the tables as ok ? Postgresql need to estimate the cardinality of each predicat to compute the best execution plan.